# Not Has signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods. "

Tags: paypal

I am a dummy developer; The problem I have is View stored in the error message: Calling Paypal action: Setexpress check out failedNot Has signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods. "

I have created and agreed to the API; Use Woo commerce and extending PayPal Digital Goods

Where am I doing wrong? 
Thanks sorry

Answer (score 1):

You need to be approved through PayPal to use Digital Goods. Depending on the type of PayPal Account you have, all you need to do is get signed up.

Just in case you need it, here is the link:

[PayPal Digital Goods Signup](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods)

If you have any trouble with signing up for the digital goods option, you can also have the flag enabled by contacting PayPal Business Support.